# Gack Id 883117290-42439 (-307661500) happens when we try to setup enhanced Einstein bot routing flow. How can we fix it?

Tags: visual-workflow, einstein-chatbot, einstein-bots, queue-based-routing

Gack Id 883117290-42439 (-307661500) happens when we try to setup enhanced Einstein bot routing flow?

How can we fix it or avoid it?

[image]

An Error Occurred with Your "Route to MessagingWebBot" Flow

You’ve received this email because an error occurred while your "Route to MessagingWebBot" flow was running.
Error element RoutingAction (FlowActionCall).
An error occurred. Try again, or contact Salesforce Customer Support and provide this error ID: 883117290-42439 (-307661500)

Answer (score 3):

This was the problem with fallback queue not having the access to the Messaging Session object.

[image]

Once we add this to the fallback queue, error is gone.

[image]